# node.js express app 404 in Facebook's iframe

Tags: facebook, node.js, express

Have setup a basic application on node.js & been trying to run it on Facebook apps platform since over 12 hours now but nothing works.

I can successfully access the application using original domain i.e., https://codebook.vaibhavpandey.com but whenever I try to access it via Facebook Apps using https://apps.facebook.com/vpz_codebook/, express renders the **404** view.

This is my main.js if you want to have a look at. My first day on node.js & Facebook Apps so don't be rude please :P

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.locals.name = 'Codebook';

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(logger('combined'));

app.use('/', index);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    var err = new Error('Oops! No code here...');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        title: err.message,
        uri: (req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl)
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

This is the routes/index.js file, containing the only route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What should the second last `app.use()` do? Not clear to me...

Comment: @Tobi I edited & added the route source

Comment: That's not what I meant. And, if I try to access the link on FB, it gives me `Requested URI http://codebook.vaibhavpandey.com/ is invalid`. Are you sure you set your app's configured location to **https://**?

Comment: @Tobi It's a 404 handler.

Comment: @BenFortune Yeah, it should be, but I think it's triggered on every request if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: No, it will only trigger if the route `/` doesn't send a response.

Comment: @BenFortune Check, and you're right. A route for POST requests has to be added, because the first request from `apps.facebook.com` will be a POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you'll have to add a route for `POST` requests as well, because the first request from `apps.facebook.com` will be a `POST`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```